# Convert an array of strings in the view Web Form View Engine format to javaScript Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

The operation is simple, I would need an inner object in javaScript.

I have the string object collection:

```
a[0] = {
name: 
"A[0].B[0].C[0].Property1"
value: "1"
}

a[1] = {
name: "A[0].B[0].C[0].Property2"
value: "1" }


a[2] = { 
name: "A[0].B[0].C[1].Property1"
value: "2"}
```

and so forth, about 100 of those.

I would like to have an object `A` with an array of `B's` and with an `Arrays` of `Cs` and each `c` with it's property. 
How to take this `A[i].B[j].C[k].Property` collection of string into one javaScript Object.

Is there any method that does like bellow ?

```
var myObject = JSON.getObject(a);
console(myObject.A[0].B[0].C[0].Property1); //output the Property1
```

Comment: At which point of the impementation of this specification are you having problems?

Comment: I don't know if there is a method that does it for you already, I am trying to develop my own by splitting the dots and creating a new object each time.
The JSON object in javaScript I didn't find good parameters.
This notation with the dots and brackets is used by the view engine of ASP.Net MVC to recognize patterns and bind it to the model, but we are doing it manually.

Comment: Ideally you want to show that code then, explain what it _does_ do (or any errors you see) and how that's different from what you _want_ it to do.  The more you post, the easier it is to know exactly what it is you need help with.

Comment: @JamesThorpe updated it with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem here is sample code

```js
var a = [];
a[0] = {
    name:
    "A[0].B[0].C[0].Property1",
    value: "1"
}

a[1] = {
    name: "A[0].B[0].C[0].Property2",
    value: "1"
}


a[2] = {
    name: "A[0].B[0].C[1].Property1",
    value: "2"
}

function createObject(arr) {
    var _a = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
        var reg = /A\[(\d+)\]\.B\[(\d+)\]\.C\[(\d+)\]\.(\w+)/g;
        var it = reg.exec(arr[i].name);
        if (it) {
            var b = _a[it[1]];
            if (!b)
                b = _a[it[1]] = [];
            var c = b[it[2]];
            if (!c)
                c = b[it[2]] = [];
            var p = c[it[3]];
            if (!p)
                p = c[it[3]] = {};
            p[it[4]] = it[4];
        }
    }
    return _a;
}

console.log(createObject(a));
```